# Open Approved Version First or Copy to new Library?

Tags: publishing, versioning

I'm sure this has been answered many times but I can't seem to find a solution. What's the consensus on how to handle the following situation:

We have a doc library that our help desk uses. The help desk users are both authors/editors and readers. When they are on a call they need to quickly view the approved version of a document. Using the OOTB versioning, obviously they're presented with the draft version of an edited document.

Is the best method to have two document libraries, one for draft/pending and one for approved? (The approved being populated by approval workflow) If so, how do you handle making edits to that document in the future? Is there a method to merge versions/documents or are we left with numerous copies of the same document?

Thanks in advance!
Josh

Comment: What's about the "Send-To" context menue?